# How to install scipy on windows 10?

Tags: python

I have windows 10 and i am trying to install scipy. Presently, I have tried pip, but it gave an error

```
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\kanika\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-4jzyxl\\scipy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().repl
```

Then i downloaded scs-1.2.6-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64 from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
and tried to run this `pip install scs-1.2.6-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64`
but still got error

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scs-1.2.6-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for scs-1.2.6-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64
```

How can i install scipy? I have numpy

**Update 1**-: I was able to install scipy but now i got error -:

```
No module named numpy+mkl
```

So i downloaded numpy-1.11.2+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl from the same link. But i get this error-:

```
Invalid requirement: 'numpy-1.11.2+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 78, in __init__
    req = Requirement(req)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 96, in __init__
    requirement_string[e.loc:e.loc + 8]))
InvalidRequirement: Invalid requirement, parse error at "'+mkl-cp2'"
```

Why am i getting this error?

Comment: To install Scipy from the link you provided you need numpy+mkl which can be found [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy). You said you have numpy but are you sure you have mkl?

Comment: @DavidG he downloaded wrong package why you down voted !! answer

Comment: @HishamKaram It was not me who downvoted

Comment: @DavidG okay thank you

Comment: rename file to `numpy.whl` and try again

Comment: I was getting that error becuase i already had numpy. So i uninstalled it and then again installed numpy+mkl. That worked. :)

Comment: happy days! you are welcome

Answer (score 13, accepted):

this is not scipy you are tring to install this is

> (unstable), a C package for solving large-scale convex cone problems.
>   Requires numpy+mkl..

on windows 64 bit to install `scipy`  use Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages  to avoid errors you can download .whl file from [Scipy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy) it's name `scipy-0.18.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl` then go to download location of file using cmd the type :

```
pip install scipy-0.18.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
```

to solve the new error download `Numpy+MKL` from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) file name is `numpy-1.11.2+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: I have mentioned in my question that i downloaded whl file of scipy from this link but it gave the error mentioned above.

Comment: this is not scipy you are trying to install you downloaded wrong file @KanikaRawat   visit link in answer to download the correct one

Comment: Which file should i download then?

Comment: it's name `scipy-0.18.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl` @KanikaRawat

Comment: Yes you were right. But i got this error no module named numpy+mkl.

Comment: @KanikaRawat update your post with the new error please

Comment: @KanikaRawat now with the same steps download `numpy+mkl` from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) file name is `numpy-1.11.2+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: Yes i downloaded this file but i got an error mentioned above. :(

Answer (score 0):

One missing part of the answers above is the install of numpy+mkl.
If not installed, many of scipy functionnalities will fail in windows.
Best and easy way is :

```
Download Wheels from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy
pip install numpy+mkl.whl
pip install scipy.whl
```

Then, error in scipy related to dll missing disappears and scipy is usable.